# Como imprimir uma constante em meio a uma string, sem concatenar?

Tags: php, constantes

Existe alguma maneira de se imprimir uma constante no meio de uma *string*, sem fazer o uso da concatenação, como se faz com as variáveis em PHP?

Exemplo:

```
 $nome = 'wallace';
 echo "Meu nome é {$nome}";
```

No caso das constantes, sei que poderia imprimir concatenando:

```
echo 'meu nome é' . NOME_USUARIO;
```

Mas eu gostaria de evitar a concatenação por achar deselegante.

Existem outros meios possíveis de se fazer isso?

Comment: Deselegante é usar constantes para exibir informações.. não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Talvez seja só a sua opnião. O que você me diz das constantes mágicas? Temos que usá-las (querendo ou não) para exibir uma linha de um arquivo, por exemplo. Nesse sentido a pergunta se torna útil. Exemplo com a resposta do @rray. `printf('A linha do arquivo é %s e o arquivo é o %s', __LINE__, __FILE__);`

Comment: Eu não faria isso concatenando, nem a pau!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode utilizar a função `printf()` para imprimir uma string formatada e depois passar os valores para *troca* ou utilizar virgula nesse caso.

```
define('NOME_USUARIO', 'lol');

echo 'meu nome é ', NOME_USUARIO;
printf('meu nome é %s', NOME_USUARIO);
```

Comment: Achei que você ia fazer `$constante = NOME_USUARIO`

Answer (score 6):

Uma possível forma também seria com algo <del>meio louco</del> mágico que o php permite: Podemos declarar o valor da função `constant` - que serve pra obter o valor da constante - e salvá-la na variável. Em seguida, chamar ela em meio a string deseja.

Veja:

```
$c = 'constant';

define('nome', 'Wallace');

echo "Meu nome é {$c('nome')}";
```

Comment: Essa ai eu não conhecia, tem algo no manual? +1.

Comment: Não vi não, @rray. Não tenho certeza, mas acho que tinha visto isso no SOEN. Não consegui achar a pergunta de novo.

Comment: xD eu tava vendo isso agora, a mesma ideia do javascript, jogar uma funçao em uma variável e depois invocar ela.

Comment: Pode ser que minha visão seja limitada nesse sentido, mas nesse exemplo eu prefiro o "TEXTO" . CONSTANTE . "TEXTO"

Comment: Sugestão para adicionar/complementar a resposta: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11910?m=46488961#46488961

Answer (score 3):

**Creio que não seja possível**, ao menos até aonde li da documentação:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

No entanto fazendo alguns testes percebi que é possível forçar/enganar a sintaxe, como o [**@Wallace fez na resposta dele**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87121/3635), no entanto a ideia aqui é criar uma variável que é uma função anonima, pois assim não precisará dos **apostrofos**, um exemplo:

```
<?php
define('FOO', 'bar');

$constant = function ($nome) {
    return $nome;
};

echo "FOO = {$constant(FOO)}";
```

Outro exemplo pegando constantes "nativas":

```
<?php
$constant = function ($nome) {
    return $nome;
};

echo "PHP_VERSION = {$constant(PHP_VERSION)}";
```

Exemplo no ideone: https://ideone.com/vSJ05m

Se não existir como `define()` vai exibir exatamente o que foi escrito:

```
<?php
$constant = function ($nome) {
    return $nome;
};

echo "BAZ = {$constant(BAZ)}"; //Exibe "BAZ = BAZ"
```

Comment: Eu nunca compreendi esse mecanismo das constantes do PHP, é diferente a forma que é feita a interpolação da constante com a string, é como se o PHP tratasse uma contaste de maneira diferente da variável. No C# 6 e superior usa o `$` seguido de uma expressão `$"{constante}"` ou `$"{variavel_comun}"` para criar uma cadeia de caracteres formatada na string.

Comment: @gato creio que seja característica de cada linguagem