# Como interpolar constantes?

Tags: php, constantes, interpolação-de-string

Por que não funciona essas interpolações e como faze-las:

```
class Foo {
    const BAR = "baz";
}

define("TAZ", "qux");

echo "Foo::BAR={Foo::BAR} TAZ={TAZ}"; //Foo::BAR={Foo::BAR} TAZ={TAZ}
echo "Foo::BAR=${Foo::BAR} TAZ=${TAZ}"; //Foo::BAR= TAZ= e 2 NOTICE Undefined variable
echo "Foo::BAR={${Foo::BAR}} TAZ={${TAZ}}"; //Foo::BAR= TAZ= e 2 NOTICE Undefined variable

//Esperado:
echo "Foo::BAR=".Foo::BAR." TAZ=".TAZ; //Foo::BAR=baz TAZ=qux
```

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [como imprimir uma constante em meio a uma string, sem concatenar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87117/como-imprimir-uma-constante-em-meio-a-uma-string-sem-concatenar)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, que estranho, [buscando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o+constante) sobre o assunto, não aparece nem a sua pergunta nem as repostas

Comment: É mais normal que você pensa, Guilherme. O sistema deixa a desejar nas pesquisas.